# how to get multiple combobox values to richlistbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a combobox1 and I added several items to it. When I select an item, that data should display in a richtextbox1. I did this and code is here

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click

    Dim x As String
    x = ComboBox1.Text
    If x = ComboBox1.Text Then
        RichTextBox1.Text = x
    End If
```

When I select several combobox1 values, such items should display on richtextbox1
but running this code richlistbox1 shows only the current combobox1 value not several values..how to do this?! I want to add several selected combobox values to the richtextbox1.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayWQY.png)

Comment: You if condition is kind of silly, don't you think?  Try `RichTextBox1.AppendText(x)` to *add* text to the control.

Comment: Lars use the answers box to post answers, unles you dont like the karma

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following instead:

```
RichTextBox1.Text &= x
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This works fine yes. Now I'm not saying you must use this, but the _recommended_ string concatenation operator is actually `&`. So in that case it would be `RichTextBox1.Text &= x`

Comment: I think he's using Lars' answer. :/